# CSS transparent radial gradient issue

Tags: html, css, image, gradient

I'm new to CSS gradients and trying to get a hold of it, I'm trying to apply a white-transparent css gradient to surround the borders of a circular div with a background image. Unfortunately the efftect I'm getting is not the desired one, how can I make the it so that the image appears less obscured by the gradient and the gradient is not as wide as it is, I want to have it only affecting the borders of the image, like maybe around 30pixels deep from the outer ring.

My code:

```css
.transparent-gradient::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  }
  .transparent-gradient{
  width:300px; height:300px; margin:20px 0px; align-self:center;position:relative; overflow:hidden; background-color:red;border-radius:50%; background-size:cover; background-position:center; background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530279281203-4c60af01ee58?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=02b66d237286bcb2a071ed6c1e72adf3&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80');
  }
```

```html
<div class="transparent-gradient" style=""></div>
```

Comment: If the answer helped you, you should check it as answered. This will help other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.transparent-gradient::after {
  content: "";
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,0) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,.9) 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.transparent-gradient{
  width:300px; 
  height:300px; 
  margin:20px 0px; 
  align-self:center;
  position:relative; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  background-color:red;
  border-radius:50%; 
  background-size:cover; 
  background-position:center; 
  background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530279281203-4c60af01ee58?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=02b66d237286bcb2a071ed6c1e72adf3&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80');
}
```

```html
<div class="transparent-gradient" style=""></div>
```

With `rgba(255,255,255,0) 40%` the `40%` specifies the "[size](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp#grad11)".
With `rgba(255,255,255,.9) 100%` the .9 you make the white less hard (opacity/ alpha from rgb**A**). `1` is complete white `.5` is `white` with `50%` opacity.